# How to match lines underlined with ****

Tags: vim

For the purposes of highlighting, how do I match lines that have been highlighted with asterisks?

```
1. Really big title
*******************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Markdown highlighting (https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/syntax/mkd.vim) plasticboy does it like this:

```
"HTML headings
syn region htmlH1       start="^\s*#"                   end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn region htmlH2       start="^\s*##"                  end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn region htmlH3       start="^\s*###"                 end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn region htmlH4       start="^\s*####"                end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn region htmlH5       start="^\s*#####"               end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn region htmlH6       start="^\s*######"              end="\($\|#\+\)" contains=@Spell
syn match  htmlH1       /^.\+\n=\+$/ contains=@Spell  "<-- Here is the one I think you want
syn match  htmlH2       /^.\+\n-\+$/ contains=@Spell
```

For completeness Markdown headers are like:

```
H1 header
=========

H2 header
---------
```